# How can I get My normal map to show on a shadeless material

Tags: game-engine, normal-map

When I add a normal map the preview material looks fine, but when I play My game it is all black unless I use shadeless. then however the normal map doesn't show up[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: I am assuming you have a light source? Also switch shading to GLSL, and go into material mode.

Answer (score -1):

is in blender render, Bake Normal Map with Low Poly Cube & Hi Poly Cube

[image: Make Bake Normal Maps In Blender Render]
[image: Mount Normal Map In The Mesh]